# Polymer Uncaught DOMException

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

I have a simple todo aap in Polymer 2. It works perfectly but when I add elements from Polymer catalog then I get the following error? And also the paper-input doesn't display properly? Check the screenshot.  Everything was working perfectly I don't know why this happened suddenly?

**dom-module.html:136 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': this name has already been used with this registry
    at http://127.0.0.1:8000/components/polymer-todo/bower_components/polymer/lib/elements/dom-module.html:136:18
    at http://127.0.0.1:8000/components/polymer-todo/bower_components/polymer/lib/elements/dom-module.html:140:3**

My code is very simple

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/lib/elements/dom-repeat.html">

<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">



<dom-module id="polymer-todo">
  <template>
   <h3>Todo:</h3>
   <dom-repeat
      items="{{tasks}}"
      as="task">
      <template>
        <div>

          <paper-checkbox ></paper-checkbox>


          <paper-input value="{{task}}"></paper-input>

        </div>
      </template>
   </dom-repeat>





    <button>Add task</button>
  </template>

  <script>
    /**
     * `polymer-todo`
     * Simple to do to add Todos
     *
     * @customElement
     * @polymer
     * @demo demo/index.html
     */
    class PolymerTodo extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() { return 'polymer-todo'; }
      static get properties() {
        return {
          tasks: {
            type: Array,
            value: () => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
            }
        };
      }
    }

    window.customElements.define(PolymerTodo.is, PolymerTodo);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

[image]

Comment: I fixed it. Actually I changed

<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html">

etc To


<link rel="import" href="../paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html">


And it worked.

Comment: why don't you propose you solution?

Comment: in general I think it's better if you stick with only one way of writing your relative import paths because otherwise you might get to the point where you import the same thing twice... and I think that might be your problem here (maybe you imported paper-checkbox somewhere else but with a different path).. or maybe at least it's just related and worth mentioning :)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. Actually I changed

`<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html">`

etc To

`<link rel="import" href="../paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html">`

And it worked.